# How to write text within a box p5.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, text, p5.js

hopefully this is a silly mistake but I am trying to write text within a rect in p5.js. My method was to convert the text to a character array and count the number of characters I am printing before increasing a y-offset to step down a line. Here is the example code:

```
  let splitQuote = tweetsTable.getRow(row).get("Quote").split('');
  let size = splitQuote.length;
  let rtnQuoteLines;
  let yOff =0;

  for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
    rtnQuoteLines += splitQuote.shift();
    if (i % 44 == 0 && i > 0) {
      let rtn = rtnQuoteLines.toString();
      text(rtn, 1100,yOff);
       console.log("rtn:    "+rtn);
      yOff += 250;
      rtnQuoteLines = "";
    }  else if (splitQuote.length < 44) {
      let rtn = splitQuote.toString();
      console.log("rtn2:    "+rtn);
      text(rtn, 1100,yOff);
      break;
    }
  }
```

The console output makes me think I'm making some mistake too because the end of the quote remains an array and the start of the quote has 'undefined' before the first character.

[image: console output]

Can anyone spot my mistake or suggest a neater way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please share a runnable [mcve]. While you're at it, I suggest using `let` or `const` in front of all variable declarations to avoid accidental globals.

Comment: At least share the content of `splitQuote`

Comment: Also, are you aware of [`textWrap()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textWrap)

Comment: textWrap() is a game changer - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First off, to stop the `undefined` at the begin, set `let rtnQuoteLines = "";` When it is initally printed it will have a value to print.

You are getting all of the commas seen in the last part of your console log because when convert an array to a string it will automatically seperate eact element with commas. To make avoid this use `let rtn = splitQuote.join("");` instead.

Hope this helps! :D